# nVidia Drivers that install when installing Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

As you all know, when installing Ubuntu, you are treated to choosing whether you want to install third-party drivers.

When I installed Ubuntu, I chose that option. After it was done installing, I noticed something. In the "Additional Drivers" tab of software-properties-gtk, it stated that there was a manually installed driver. Therefore, it is implied that a different nVidia driver than the normal one is installed, specifically for Ubuntu.

Could anyone tell me which one is it and state the package name of this driver too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one did you choose during installation and which one is currently selected?

Comment: @Nmath I chose the "Install proprietary drivers during installation option". In the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software and Updates", it said that there was a manually installed driver.